# Why my GetAttribute returns null, code seems ok to me

Tags: javascript, html

[HTML code jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4gHD.png)

[JavaScript code jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8AQy.png)

Comment: Please do not share images of code and/or errors. Instead, copy and paste them here. You should do this since it is impossible to debug screenshots.

And please tell us what problem you are having and what you have done to try and fix it. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

getAttribute returns the values of attributes in your tags, consider the following `<input attr1='a' attr2='b' attr3='c'>foo</input>`

`getAttribute(attr1)` you get 'a'

`getAttribute(attr2)` you get 'b'

`getAttribute(attr3)` you get 'c'

You have two choices either use  `.style.fontSize` if you have inline styles.

Or if you don't you have to use `Window.getComputedStyle()` to get the font-size.

```
let computedFontSize = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("foo")).fontSize;
```

The variable computedFontSize will return with the font size with unit. Unit can be px, em, %. You need to strip out the unit to do an arithmetic operation and assign the new value.

reference links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle